# R ggplot geom_points not aligned with boxplot bins

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame and want to make boxplots and plot geom_points on them. But the points are not centered with the bins. I tried to replicate the issue with the mtcars data frame but wasn't able to so - because it worked there! So I uploaded this data:

[Link to Google Drive with a small csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xfccyWfubi_QlUnNHVOyJyRZZ55h55JD/view?usp=sharing)

I am doing my little code:

```
    df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("value1", "value2"), 
               names_to = "new") %>%
  group_by(factor, new)

ggplot(df, aes(x = new, y = value, fill = as.factor(factor))) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point()
```

And get this plot with the misaligned points:

[image]

How can I center the points on each respective bin?

Comment: Try with `geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = .75))` to align the points with the boxplots. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21468520/12993861 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654960/ggplot2-line-up-geom-point-with-split-boxplots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Unlike `geom_boxplot()`, `geom_point()` doesn't dodge by default -- you need to specify `position = position_dodge()`.
2. This still won't quite work, because there are some `NA`s in `factor` -- this will cause your points to be dodged across three groups, which won't align correctly. You can remove the `NA`s using `drop_na(factor)`.

```
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("value1", "value2"), 
               names_to = "new") %>%
  drop_na(factor) %>% 
  group_by(factor, new)

ggplot(df, aes(x = new, y = value, fill = as.factor(factor))) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = .75))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the issue was really missing values and an imaginary third bin.