# Adding points from other dataset to boxplot: how to separate based on same fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am trying to recreate this plot:

[image]

I have data on actual habitat presence and random data on expected habitat presence for 8 years. I want to see if the presence of bird species depends on the presence of certain crop types.

The code for the plot looks like this:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot (data = random_soort2, aes(x=categorie, y=fractie, fill=type)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  geom_point (data = sum_echt, aes(x=categorie, y = mean, fill=type),colour="red")
```

And creates the following plot:

[image]

The problem is that the red dots of the actual data are not separated by type, but are all grouped together. How do I separate them based on type?

Comment: You should provide some reproducible example. My guess is that you should use `color=type` instead of `fill=type` and remove the argument `color = red` outside the parenthesis. Type should probably be a factor column

Comment: Most likely issue is that `geom_point` uses `position="identity"` by default. To align the points with dodged box plots try `position = position_dodge(width = .75)`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71287108/r-ggplot-geom-points-not-aligned-with-boxplot-bins

Comment: check also the ggbeeswarm package